# Bootstrap: Empty uncolored space between columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest Bootstrap for a grid system, but I run into a problem:

If you see the Grid System examples on [this url](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), you will see that all columns are completely attached to one another, meaning that the "gutter" between them is as well colored, since the "gutter" is created with `padding` and not with `margin`, therefore it gets affected by `background-color`.

Is there a way to make that the gutter between 2 columns is left white and uncolored? [Here](http://grids.heroku.com/grid?column_width=60&column_amount=12&gutter_width=20) is an example of what I want to achieve.

PS: I know I could use any other grid framework, but for this project, Bootstrap is a requisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Add a transparent border to cols:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

- Or add a child div in your cols so padding will be the margin of your child div

Comment: I will go with option #2, as it doesnt hack into bootstrap. Thanks!